# XSLT: why /*/* overrides /*/x?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm studing XSLT and I've the following problem. I've this XML:

```
<a>
<x>testo 0
    <rad>testo 1</rad>
</x>
<b>
    <p>
        <w>
            <z>testo 2</z>
        </w>
    </p>
</b>
<y>
    <p/>
    <y>testo 3
        <d>testo 4</d>
    </y>
</y>
<f/>
```

which should be translated into thix xml, with XSLT 1.0:

```
<r>
<nx>
<oldx/>
<new>
<rad/>
</new>
</nx>
<b>
<new>
<p/>
</new>
</b>
<new>
<p/>
</new>
<new>
<y/>
</new>
<f/>
</r>
```

Here's my attempt:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="r">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/x">
        <nx><xsl:element name="oldx"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/></nx>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/y">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <new>
            <xsl:element name="{name()}"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </new>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but when I apply this transformation, and the program is going to translate the x element, it applies this template: /* /* rather than /*/x.

I know that /* /* matches every "children" of the root, but from what I know /*/x should have the priority on the x element. Can you help me to understand what's wrong with my XSLT?

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
for example if I've this input:

```
<a> <c> <a> 
    <b>1</b>
    <b>2</b>
</a>
    <f><b>3</b>
    </f>
</c>
    <b> <c>4</c> 5 </b>
</a>
```

and I apply this transofmration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="a">
        <A><xsl:apply-templates/></A> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="b"> 
        <B><xsl:value-of select="."/></B>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*"> 
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

element "a", "b", "c" are matched as I expect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that neither has priority. Look at the XSLT Recommendation for details of how template priority works (it's much less sophisticated than you'd expect), and when in doubt set priorities explicitly.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict

or, from the 2.0 spec, but essentially the same and possibly more readable:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict

Comment: How do you "set priority explicitly"?

Comment: set the `priority` attribute on the `<xsl:template>` element to a number higher or lower than the default (or, more specifically, that of the conflicting element)

Comment: @keshlam: thanks for your reply. Can you look at the edit I made at the end of the first post? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't edit posts to add supplementary questions. It's hopeless to try and follow a thread if the question has been changed since the answers were written. Once a question has been answered, only edit it to fix simple errors. For supplementary questions, if they can't be handled through comments, start a new post.